# Flutter failed to build on Android due to icon_tree_shaker

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

After updating Flutter to 1.20.2 (also tried 1.20.1) app failed to build android apk in release mode.

After

```
flutter build apk
```

I got error

```
Script '/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 896
```

And after

```
flutter build apk -v
```

error in build

```
[   +1 ms] [        ] Failed to subset font; aborting.
[   +2 ms] [   +8 ms] Target aot_android_asset_bundle failed: FontSubset error: Font subsetting failed with exit code 255.
[        ]            #0      IconTreeShaker.subsetFont (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/icon_tree_shaker.dart:213:7)
```

p.s.

After updating Flutter to 1.20.1 problem with icon tree shaker was also on iOS - but [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60325) has the solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution was found

If you have same issue, you can run

> flutter build apk --no-tree-shake-icons